# Android Kit used x86_64 and Android SDK (Google API's x86_64 system image) and JDK-Eclipse Termurin JDK with Hotspot 21.0.2 +13 (x64)

Tags: android, qt

The deployment device "Emulator" does not support the architectures used by the kit.
The kit supports "", but the device uses "x86_64".
Error while building/deploying project stream6 (kit: Android Qt 6.5.3 Clang x86_64)
When executing step "Deploy to Android device"

which version will support JDK,Android SDK for that toolkit